# Active Report 10 Multi Data set designer issue

Tags: activereports

This is driving me nuts and I can't for the life of me find anything and it seems like such a small problem. I have been trying to google stuff but half the results lead to dead broken links. So here I am.

I am trying to create a SIMPLE report with Active Report 10 just textbox nothing fancy. I have to data sets A and B. When I click on the textbox to assign values at the initial start I am asked which data set I want A or B and such.

Now after the first initial assignment I lose the option to switch and use the other data set. I know I can switch between data set because I have seen it done in other reports that are sent to me and I tried setting the data set name in the property but nothing works.

This seems like I am missing something blatantly obvious. This is all done inside the designer and no code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel dumb after fiddling around I created a new report and try another template and used RDL report instead of page report. That seems to have done the trick . . . god knows why they all you to add multi data set and can't use it in page report.

Comment: In a Page Reports, the page itself is bound to the data set, for example an invoice page would be bound to a single invoice record or order record.   For that reason you cannot use more than one data set on that report.

Comment: @GrapeCityTeam Yep learn that the hard way although it is very miss leading in the designer.

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct.  I will pass it on to the design team.  regards.